# (Why) does this design suck?

Tags: avr, pcb, ethernet, rfid, pcb-design

I'm designing an Open Hardware door-lock-controller for our hackerspace, to these basic requirements:

- Be made exclusively from available and inexpensive parts.
- Read external Wiegand keyboard
- Read external Wiegand RFID reader
- Control various door-locks and other actuators.
- Read 125 kHz EM4100 RFID directly with an onboard reader.
- Passive POE powered, to make cabling easier.
- Run off unregulated 15-30V DC (cheap and easy high-capacity UPS via SLA)
- Provide a regulated 12V DC out @ 300 mA to 1.5A peak for external gear.
- Talk Ethernet to the server.
- Keep a local list of allowable keys, so only power is needed to let us in.
- Control external 230V gear using two relays.

This is the second spin of the PCB with a few changes to fix the problems I've found, the biggest change I've made is to throw away the LDO that regulated the 3.3V rail, in exchange for a simple MC34063 based switcher.

I'm pretty sure it's going to work, but I'd like some comments to check if I've overlooked something.

Compromises I've had to make in the design are:

- The primary (35V) capacitor is stacked on top of the Ethernet transformer to save space.
- The Ethernet transformer is huge, but I have a bunch of them and they were cheap, so I'm going to use them, even if they are huge.

## Main questions

- Is there a cheaper and better way to implement the two power supplies (I need around 200mA@3.3V and 300mA@12V with peaks to 1.5A) ?
- Does the MC34063 switcher circuit/layout look sane?
- I have no idea how inefficient the MC34063 is so I've tried to heat sink it as well as possible using the copper I have available, any hints for improvements?

[Schematic in pdf](http://www.hackaarhus.dk/forum/download/file.php?id=33)

[Click to embiggen PCB image](http://www.hackaarhus.dk/forum/download/file.php?id=32)
[image]

Comment: What does "passive POE" mean?  Some sort of non-standard wiring that looks almost exactly like standard Ethernet that may cause severe damage to anything that is inadvertently plugged into it?  802.3af POE has intelligence for good reason.

Comment: passive POE is the non-standard way of doing POE that simply uses the two extra pairs for power, it's very common in certain fields because it's cheap and efficient at both ends of the cable.

Comment: How did it work out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd be really surprised if this operates, at least with any reliability.  You desperately need a power plane and a ground plane with components like these.

For instance the ENC28J60SS is a current mode driver, those traces from it to the pulse transformer to the jack are going to be carrying high currents switching at high speeds with no reasonable supply or ground path for them.  I'd also be concerned with the crystal as its tuning capacitors have a very long high inductance path to ground.  I would guess that this design will emit a ton of EMI, possibly enough to interfere with any nearby electronics.

The layout for the switcher is also huge, i would expect you to have serious amounts of noise and supply ringing throughout this design coming from the switcher and the ethernet components.

You also mentioned POE but there is no POE controller on this board.  If your planning to just plug into a POE switch there is a negotiation procedure to request power (in various levels).  The only way you could power this off the ethernet port as is would be to find a mid run injector that just dumped voltage on the unused pairs in 10/100 Base-T.  If you plugged this into a gigabit switch that could cause major problems.  Those pairs also aren't center tapped as they should be for POE.  Dumping pins 7/8 directly to ground could cause major problems for both this device and the switch.

There is a lot i could go into but 90% of it is a result of not having power/ground planes, clear that up first.

Also the mid point of R5 and R6 should not be connected to the center tap of the pulse transformer and the jack side of the Output transformer should have a small, high voltage cap to chassis ground at its center tap

Comment: I'm with Mark on this one. it's a neat (as in tidy) design, but it's not a very good one. I recently designed a PoE board and used the LM5071 PoE switchmode controller; it was a breeze to build, works very well and would give you the types of voltages at the current levels you are asking for. Also, your large electrolytic caps are overlapping other parts/access screws, it might be tricky to mount.

Comment: About the power planes: I'm not going to use more than two layers of PCB, so I can't spare two layers for power, but I will certainly reorganize the Ethernet components to allow me to get a largeish local groundplane under them, tighten up the power supply around it and to get the crystal+caps tightened up.

Comment: About the POE: Yes, I'm not using standard POE, but the, in some fields, more common non-standard passive POE.

Comment: About R5&R6: They aren't connected to the center tap, I'm just sloppy at drawing, sorry.

Comment: About the switcher: Yes, it's sort of spread out, but other than to turn the MC34063 90 degrees to get a shorter wire from pin 2 to the coil and the diode I don't see how I could possibly tighten it up.

Comment: anything short of at least a full, solid, ground plane is a waste of time.  The sectional pours do little to nothing to solve the problem unless they extend all the way, unbroken, to the supply ground connection, even then if signals pass over the edge of the plane you've created another problem.  You don't need 2 separate power layers, you can split the plane for +3.3V and +12V just be careful about routing over the split on adjacent layers.  The only way you'll get this design to be reliable is a 4 layers board.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I don't have more then two layers to play with, so there is no full ground plane in the future of this design. The old layout actually works and there are plenty of cases where people use EN28J60 on two layer boards, which btw. is a 10 megabit part.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, even the budget forbids anything more than 2 layers. I have been able to tighten up the ENC28J60 and the switcher layouts quite a bit and fatten up the power traces, so there ought to be some chance that it will all work out.

Comment: I know the part, there is a fairly long list of people that have tried to use it and failed FCC miserably at 200Mhz.  I had problems with a pic18f97J60 which shares the same current mode drive circuitry and had to be very careful with it on a 6 layer controlled impedance board to clear FCC.  Look at the ethernet output around 200Mhz, you'll probably find a nasty ~50mV ripple on it.  For your application it may be fine but i'd be curious to see what happens when the ethernet port is driving and the relay switches.

Comment: Thankfully it's not going to be a consumer product, so it will not have to pass FCC or be CE certified. I will stick the board in a nice tight metal box to keep the EMI inside, so I'm mainly concerned with getting something that works for me than something that works for the FCC:)

Comment: well, the metal enclosure won't help much, the emissions will radiate from the various wires that will be attached to this.  The noise in the ethernet portion won't be contained to the ethernet section.  It will propagate throughout the design and present on all signals and wires going in or out of the design.  Additionally its not just an FCC issue.  Ground bounce and supply ringing will impact the reliability of the entire design.  This is a door lock after all, there is a large difference between it working on your bench and it working to secure your space for months on end.

Comment: All very helpful comments. However, We've got a 2 layer board (most of one layer is gnd) with Ethernet, PoE and RFID showering the board, and it sailed through EMC and is very reliable.